# How to evaluate a single connection in whonix workstation

Tags: whonix

I want to know which way a request has gone (`guard-/middle-/exitnode`). In TBB I saw this easily. I tried to watch the connections at whonix gateway but I guess I am wrong because nothing changes although I have made a new identity in tor browser. How can I follow my connections?

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://www.dnsleaktest.com/ . It shows your ip adress and the position of this.

Comment: thanks for your response! so ther is no way which entry- and middlenode i am using? like the feature in the tor browser bundle?